# Wrong extrinsic parameters from stereoCalibrate OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, linear-algebra, camera-calibration

I have two cameras (same model so same intrinsic parameters) in a stereo setup and I would like to evaluate the quality of the stereo calibration I obtained from stereoCalibrate and stereoRectify using ~100 images for the calibration process. (I used arround the same amount of images to get intrinsic parameters of both cameras)

To achieve that, I have the precise 3D location of 4 points in the room as well as the location of my cameras through other, trustworthy means.
I then triangulate the 4 points by filming them with my cameras and apply the right scale to my coordinates to have the same scale as the reference positions(found by other means) and then apply an icp algorithm to match these points to the "real ones".
Finally, I take a look at the position of the center of my camera basis (0,0,0 in each basis) and compare it to the real position of my cameras, and they are completely off.

The problem is that the triangulation is on point, which leads me to think that my way of reconstructing camera positions from the transformation matrix between Cam1 and Cam2 is wrong.

Here is the code I use as well as screenshots explaining the problem :

```
# undst_points_i were undistorted using the camera matrix and undistortion coefficients from calibrateCamera as well as Pi and Ri from stereRectify with undistortPoints
# p1 and p2 found using stereoRectify
undst_points_1 = cv2.undistortPoints(src=points_1.astype(np.float32), cameraMatrix=cameraMatrix, distCoeffs=distortionCoeff, R=R1, P=P1).squeeze()
undst_points_2 = cv2.undistortPoints(src=points_2.astype(np.float32), cameraMatrix=cameraMatrix, distCoeffs=distortionCoeff, R=R2, P=P2).squeeze()

X = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1[:3], P2[:3], undst_points_1.T, undst_points_2.T)
X = X / X[3]
X = X[:3].T #X is a list containg my 4 triangulated points

transform_mat = np.zeros(shape=(4,4))
transform_mat[:3,:3] = R #R found with stereoCalibrate
transform_mat[:3,3] = T.squeeze() #T found with stereoCalibrate
transform_mat[3,3] = 1

pos_cam1 = [0,0,0]
pos_cam2 = np.linalg.inv(transform_mat).dot(np.asarray([0,0,0,1]).T).T[:3]
#Now pos_cam2 should represent the center of camera2 basis in camera1 coordinates

X *= 34 #I used a checkerboard with 34mm square size
pos_cam2 *= 34

#Now the real coordinates and the ones from the calibration are at the same scale
new_coordinates = apply_best_fit_transform(X, real_points, list(X) + [pos_cam1, pos_cam2]) #This transforms all my points to be placed in the same space as my reference mesurement (its a solid transformation, it doesn't change the scale)

plot_3D_points(new_coordinates, real_points+[real_cam_1, real_cam_2]) #Function that just plots the points
```

Here is the value of R:

```
array([[ 0.62977833, -0.00846942, -0.77672873],
   [ 0.01220839,  0.99992497, -0.00100447],
   [ 0.77667896, -0.00885002,  0.62983448]])
```

Value of T:

```
array([[67.60332964],
   [-1.11401288],
   [30.95438459]])
```

Value of transform_mat:

```
array([[ 6.29778334e-01, -8.46941672e-03, -7.76728730e-01,
     6.76033296e+01],
   [ 1.22083925e-02,  9.99924970e-01, -1.00446931e-03,
    -1.11401288e+00],
   [ 7.76678959e-01, -8.85001620e-03,  6.29834480e-01,
     3.09543846e+01],
   [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00]])
```

Value of cameraMatrix:

```
array([[444.1141759 ,   0.        , 193.05169162],
   [  0.        , 443.74264676, 292.62104944],
   [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]])
```

Value of distortionCoeff:

```
array([[-0.00297081, -0.01677297, -0.01437427,  0.00396268, -0.03044387]])
```

Value of R1:

```
array([[ 0.89566747, -0.02636362, -0.44394227],
   [ 0.02526932,  0.99964553, -0.00838254],
   [ 0.4440059 , -0.00371015,  0.89601618]])
```

Value of R2:

```
array([[ 9.09117969e-01, -1.49810539e-02,  4.16269249e-01],
   [ 1.39586185e-02,  9.99887449e-01,  5.49965410e-03],
   [-4.16304788e-01,  8.10709286e-04,  9.09224761e-01]])
```

Value of P1:

```
array([[-1.75916832e+03,  0.00000000e+00,  8.73543620e+01,
     0.00000000e+00],
   [ 0.00000000e+00, -1.75916832e+03,  3.13292581e+02,
     0.00000000e+00],
   [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,
     0.00000000e+00]])
```

Value P2:

```
array([[-1.75916832e+03,  0.00000000e+00,  8.73543620e+01,
    -1.30814306e+05],
   [ 0.00000000e+00, -1.75916832e+03,  3.13292581e+02,
     0.00000000e+00],
   [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,
     0.00000000e+00]])
```

Position for my real points (points observed as well as camera lense):

```
real_points = [np.array([  379.456665, -2603.414551,  1127.278442]), np.array([  219.311081, -2602.786865,  1125.915161]), np.array([  138.821686, -2599.333984,  1125.838379]), np.array([  220.28302 , -2566.926514,  1011.536499])]

real_cam_1 = np.array([-1102.98645 ,   646.044189,  1608.366699])
real_cam_2 = np.array([1627.534424,  423.98819 , 1607.142945])
```

Position of the observed points on the images from my cameras :

[Circles are the points obtained from calibration (4 points forming a "T" shape and the two cameras) and x are the real points I should find (cameras ares represented with a group of 3 "x")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8tP3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUIYc.png)

I should also add that using solvePnP didn't really help as it gave me different results, but equally as bad. Also, the norm of my translation vector (obtained from calibrateCamera then multiplied by 34) is different than the real distance between my two cameras.

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: calibration data required. [mre]